# SSIS Script Task - How to store xml content in project parameter and refer it in Script Task

Tags: xml, ssis

I have a XML with below content

```
<?xml version ="1.0"?>
<tables>
 <table id = "1">A</table>
 <table id = "2">B</table>
</tables>
```

And I refer the XML content inside of the project parameter in Script Task, i.e.

[image: project parameter]

But I am getting the error

> illegal character in path

and the XML is not getting loaded error while executing package. Below line I have used in Script Task:

```
XElement xe = XElement.Load(Dts.Variables["$Project::pXML].Value.ToString());
```

Please suggest what change I need to make.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `XElement.Parse(...)`
It loads XML from the string.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `XmlDocument` instead of `XElement`:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(Dts.Variables["$Project::pXML"].Value.ToString());
```